# NXT Program doesn't do what it's supposed to do

Tags: nxt, motor, nxt-g

Ok, so I have this automatic gearbox I have made and I have 2 motors and 2 touch sensors

I want Motor A to spin forever unless Motor B is turning

Motor B should turn around 15 degrees and then brake. The direction depends on what touch sensor is pushed. I created this piece of block code thing (personally don't like) but it looks like it should work but it doesn't.

[image]

Motor A spins forever and when B is activated, it spins forever too completely destroying the gearbox :(

Pseudo Code:

```
If Touch1 == Bumped Then
    Stop MotorB
    Rotate MotorA by 15 degrees
Else If Touch2 == Bumped Then
    Rotate MotorA by -15 degrees
    Stop MotorB
Else
    Rotate MotorB Forever

(I know this is horrrible pseudo code but you get the jist)
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Your text description does not match the picture or pseudo code - motor A and motor B are mixed up. You should fix that for future readers. Also, your pseudo code is not horrible, it is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make the blocks match your pseudo code. The missing part is "Stop Motor B". Adding blocks to stop motor B will help.

Also, stop motor B needs to be before starting motor A, otherwise motor A will run while motor B is running.

```
If Touch1 == Bumped Then
    Stop MotorB
    Rotate MotorA by 15 degrees
Else If Touch2 == Bumped Then
    Stop MotorB
    Rotate MotorA by -15 degrees
Else
    Rotate MotorB Forever
```

[image]